# Prove: The null space is equal to the orthogonal complement of the image space

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetry

I need to prove:

> Let $V$ be a real linear space with an inner product. Prove that if $A:V\to V$ is a symmetric linear operator, then the null space of $A$ is orhogonal to the image space of $A$.

I only have $N \subseteq R^\perp$: Take a random $x\in N$ and a  random $y\in R, y=Au$. Then $(x,y)=(x,Au)=(Ax,u)=(0,u)=0 \implies x\in  R^\perp \implies N\subseteq R^\perp$

Edit: But I still need to prove the other side

Comment: I'll try to rewrite it. Let me know if it is correct

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29072/how-is-the-column-space-of-a-matrix-a-orthogonal-to-its-nullspace

Answer (score 3):

To prove the stronger statement you indicate after the question in the highlighted box, note that
\begin{align}
    w \in \mathcal{R}(A)^{\perp} &\iff (Av,w)=0\;\forall v\in V \\
                      &\iff (v,Aw)=0\;\forall v\in V \\
                      &\iff Aw=0
\end{align}
The last equivalence holds because $Aw=0$ implies $(v,Aw)=0$ for all $v$, and because, if $(v,Aw)=0$ for all $v\in V$, then it holds for $v=Aw$, which implies $Aw=0$. Therefore,
$$
       \mathcal{R}(A)^{\perp} = \mathcal{N}(A).
$$
Hence,
$$
              V = \mathcal{R}(A)\oplus\mathcal{R}(A)^{\perp}=\mathcal{R}(A)\oplus\mathcal{N}(A).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in R^{\perp}$, then $(x,Av)=0$, for all $v\in V$.

In particular, $(Ax,Ax)=(x,AAx)=0$, so $Ax=0$ and $x\in N$. 
Therefore $R^{\perp}\subset N$

Comment: Sorry i dont really understand your answer, this is probably because sometimes only 1 side of the $<$ is filled in, so i cant see for sure if this is good or wrong

Comment: I edited in order to use the same notation as the OP, which should make this clearer.