# Questions regarding orthogonal subspaces of an $n \times m$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

For an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ of rank $r$,

1. Is it true that while the dimension of the null space and row space of $A$ add up to $n$, the union of the two vector spaces may not cover entire $R^n$? I think it is as geometrically in $R^3$, we could have one space be a plane while the other be a line that is orthogonal to that plane, but the union of the two would not cover the entirety of $R^3$.
2. If I take a basis of row space of $A$ ($\{v_1, v_2, .. v_r\}$) and a basis for the null space of $A$ ($\{n_1, ... n_{n-r}\}$), does vector space spanned by the union of the two basis equal $R^n$? I can see that it probably does geometrically, but is there an algebraic way to show this?

Comment: Check out $A = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. And you mean the sum, not the union...

Comment: The title is also misleading. There is no orthogonality involved here.

Comment: Do you mean $n \times m $ or $m \times n $? There is a contradiction there.

Comment: The union of two vector spaces is almost never itself a vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any matrix $A_{m\times n}$, with rank $r \leq \min(m, n)$, one can show that $R(A^T) = N(A)^{\perp}$. You can see the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29072/how-is-the-column-space-of-a-matrix-a-orthogonal-to-its-nullspace). It means row space of $A$ is orthogonal to it's null space, and $dim(R(A^T)+N(A)) = n$. i.e. the basis of row space of A, and null space of A, can span the entire $\mathbb R^n$. Any vector in $\mathbb R^n$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors in the basis of row space and null space of A. As for your first question, the union of two subspaces need not necessarily be a subspace. This is expanied in this thread [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71872/union-of-two-vector-subspaces-not-a-subspace).

Comment: Can I also approach it this way: the $n-r$ vectors in the basis for the null space of A is orthogonal to the $r$ vectors in the basis for the row space of A (assume both are subspaces of $R^n$ and $A$ has rank $r$). Hence every vector in the union of the two basis are linearly independent, and we have $n$ vectors in this union, so this set of vectors must span $R^n$?

Comment: Yes. Union of set of basis vectors of row space and null space can span entire $\mathbb R^n$. This is not the same as saying union of row space and null space is  $\mathbb R^n$.